# Remove characters in string - and add it to array - Regex - Powershell - Migration

Tags: powershell, string

I'm trying to migrate data from a Excel spreadsheet to user profile properties.

Data ex:

> Energy & Resources;#67777;#Financial Services;#137;#Consumer Business & Transportation;#23;#Real Estate;#4

How can I format the text to be like:

> Energy & Resources;Financial Services;Consumer Business & Transportation;Real Estate;

Regex:
[rexex example](http://regexr.com/3af2l)

How can I manage to get it into a array

```
$text = "Energy & Resources;#67;#Financial Services;#137"

$text -replace ";[#\d;]+"
```

Then I get: Energy & Resources  that is correct for the first value, but how do I get all in a array?

[1](http://regexr.com/3af2l)Energy & Resources
[2]Financial Services
[3]Consumer Business & Transportation
[4].........

Comment: did you try ";[#\d;]+/g" the /g is for global replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-replace` PowerShell Regex based operator:

```
$line = "Energy & Resources;#67777;#Financial Services;#137;#Consumer Business & Transportation;#23;#Real Estate;#4"
$fmtLine = $line -replace ";[#\d;]+", ';'
```

Update

In order to return the array of values use `-split` operator or  [String.Split method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
$line = "Energy & Resources;#67777;#Financial Services;#137;#Consumer Business & Transportation;#23;#Real Estate;#4"
$fmtline = $line -replace ";[#\d;]+", ';'  
$values = $fmtline.Split(';', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

[PowerShell: Working With Regular Expressions (regex)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4310.powershell-working-with-regular-expressions-regex.aspx)